# What happens if a page with an invalid SSL cert responds with a 302 redirect to a page with a valid cert? Do you still get the warning?

Tags: tls, web-browser

1. Alice navigates to `https://example.com`.
2. `https://example.com` delivers an invalid certificate.
3. `https://example.com` 302 redirects to `https://www.example.com`
4. `https://www.example.com` delivers a valid certificate.

*Question*: will Alice see a warning on step 3

Comment: This is a common problem that can occur if a site is hosted entirely in SSL. Buying an SSL certificate with a SAN (subject alternative name) will get around this problem. Entrust offers one SAN "free" with each of their certificates. Not sure about the other vendors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alice will see a warning. This is because the certificate is checked at the point where the SSL negotiation happens, which is **before** you get the contents of the page - whether those contents are an HTML page or a status code with a redirect.

For an example of why this is important, imagine this scenario:

Evul manages (e.g. by DNS cache poisoning or some other technique) to get you to go to his server instead of the real `https://example.com`. Evul does not have a correct cert for `https://example.com`, but he wants to redirect you to a page for which he *does* have a valid certificate, for instance his very own site `https://www.evulkrakker.com`, knowing that once you're redirected there you'll see that it has a valid certificate.

If there were no warning at the first site, you'd never know that you were redirected to his evil site.